# How to change my .m file to a .mm file?

Tags: xcode, file, error-handling, cocos2d-iphone, lexical

How can I change my .m file to a .mm file?

I'm getting the error: cassert file not found

I have researched and found that I need to change my files to .mm?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are in XCode you can simply select the file in the Project Navigator, after selecting it, wait a moment, click on it again and the filename will automatically be selectable. You can then change the filename to '.mm'